# How to control for a variable that interacts with my DV?

Tags: regression, interaction

I am investigating the effect of using different percent compliances (`percent`) in a public health message on behavior (`behavior`). I also measured the believability of the message (`believe`).

I now want to control for individuals' belief in the manipulation, but there is a significant interaction between `believe` and `percent`. I'm only actually interested in the effect of `percent` on `behavior`, so is the right regression to run one that includes the interaction term, or one that leaves it out?

(I should perhaps mention that I am expecting a quadratic effect, so I have `percent^2` as a term as well).

Comment: The correlation is between a predictor and the response variable or between predictors?

Comment: Welcome! So you also investigate the effect of ‘percent’ on believability? Were both ‘behavior’ and ‘believe’ separately used as dependent variables?

Comment: @Dave @ThomasBilach: The correlation is between the predictors. I manipulated `percent` and measured both `behavior` and `believe`, intending for `believe` to be a covariate. My model currently is `behavior~percent+percent^2+believe`, but the interactions are significant as well. What I'm not clear on is whether I need to include the interactions to correctly interpret the effect of `behavior~percent+percent^2`.

Comment: What is the goal of fitting your mode?

Comment: @Dave I want to understand the main effect of percent on behavior. But obviously the significance & coefficients change depending on whether or not I add the interactions in the model.